# In Calendar add subtract in java

Tags: java

I trying to subtract 60 days from calender . sample code

```
   try {


        cal.set(2014,02,12);  //year,month,date
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -60);

        System.out.println("Year = " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        System.out.println("Month = " + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)));
        System.out.println("Day = " + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The output is

```
Year = 2014
Month = 0
Day = 11
```

if the date is

```
cal.set(2014,01,12);  //year,month,date
```

output is fine :

```
Year = 2013
Month = 11
Day = 14
```

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: If you [read the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29), it clearly states that the MONTH is 0-based. 0 for January.

Comment: What's the problem?  `Calendar` use `0` based months (so January is `0`)...

Comment: Month is 0 indexed, meaning Year = 2014 Month = 0 Day = 11 is jan 11 2014, which is the date 60 days before 12 march 2014

Comment: Do you have to use `Calendar`? [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (or [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)) is a lot easier to work with.

Comment: using java.util.Calendar only...     
 
plz note .. year also not changing Year = 2014 only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong you are getting the January month, as [months start from 0](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29)

> **month -** the value used to set the MONTH calendar field. Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.

So what you are getting is 11-January-2014

**EDIT:-**

Based on the comments below are the months representation:

- January: 0
- February: 1
- March: 2
- April: 3
- May: 4
- June: 5
- July: 6
- August: 7
- September: 8
- October: 9
- November: 10
- December: 11

So your date 2014,**02**,12 actually represents 12-**March**-2014 and when you are deleting 60 days from it then it will take you to January, and so the year will not change.

Comment: plz note .. year also not changing  Year = 2014 only

Comment: @JohnRaja:- Because the year would remain the same. 2 represents March. And 60 days when subtracted from March 2014 takes you to January 2014

Comment: all months working fine. but problem only for February

Comment: @JohnRaja:- February is 1. I am not sure where you are confused?

Comment: 2014,02,12 -- output is Year = 2014 Month = 0 Day = 11 .. why not changing year as 2013 ..

Comment: @JohnRaja:- I have explained more in my answer. The 02 is March and when you delete 60 days from March, it would take you to January of the same year!